# If variables in the global context are properties, then how are they distinguished for the purposes of closures?

Tags: javascript

If variables in the global context are properties (on the global context), then how are they distinguished from other properties on the global context  for the purposes of closures?

Obviously this doesn't work:

```
function foo() {
   this.a = 'a';
   this.bar = function() { console.log(a); }
}

new foo().bar(); // ReferenceError: a is not defined
```

Obviously this does work:

```
var a = 'a';
function bar() {
  console.log(a);
}
bar(); // a
```

But how given that variable `a` is a "property". Where is my misunderstanding?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are not distinguished - they are simply both a variable and a property. You might imagine that the global scope is the only scope object that is accessible as an actual language object.

The [global environment](http://es5.github.io/#x10.2.3) consists of an environment record that is bound (like a `with` statement) to the global object, which itself is exposed as the `window` object in browsers.

To use your constructor example:

```
function Foo() {
   with (this) {
      this.a = 'a';
      this.bar = function() { console.log(a); }
      // Is `a` a variable or a property? It's *one* thing, available as both.
   }
}

new Foo().bar(); // 'a'
```

Comment: Yuck, [never use the `with` statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/with).

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara: Except for explanation and exhibition of crazy language details :-)

Comment: `with` finds a valid use! Thanks

Comment: Why is this possibly a good answer?  [From MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/with): `Use of the with statement is not recommended, as it may be the source of confusing bugs and compatibility issues. See the "Ambiguity Con" paragraph in the "Description" section below for details.`  Further, `with` is not legal in strict mode.

Comment: @jfriend001 My question was about how the interpreter resolves variables. This answer uses a illegal-in-strict-mode language feature *for illustrative purposes only*.

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara apparently, according to some content somewhere, there are performance implications for `with` statements; however, I don't mind them "aesthetically" which is one reason they are discouraged (apparently, according to some content somewhere, people didn't like debugging them). It is interesting, though, that people do have such opinions about them. My former boss hated them. I thought it was just a quirk, but, apparently, there is a large contingent of people (if not the majority of ECMAScript programmers) that do not like them.

Comment: @jfriend00 the same statement is found (I think *ver batim*) in "[JavaScript for Professional Web Developers](http://www.amazon.com/Professional-JavaScript-Developers-Nicholas-Zakas/dp/1118026691)" (2012). This would be the "some content somewhere" I mentioned. Looks like it's all over the place. I wonder if the cited confusion is why it is not permitted in strict mode?

Comment: @jfriend00—MDN is not an authority, it's just a public wiki and full of personal opinions, jargon and imperfections—but it's a lot better than alternatives. Sure, *with* is considered a bad feature, but it's still there in the ed. 6 draft, not even deprecated. ;-)

Comment: @RobG - so are you recommending that you program with `with` and therefore don't use `strict` mode?  And, do you think the advantages of strict mode are a controversial opinion?

Answer (score 2):

*Global scope* is `window` object in Web browsers. Thus, a variable declaration in the global scope becomes a property of `window`.

```
// Somewhere in the global scope...
// Both declarations add a property to window
window.a = "hello world";
var a = "hello world";
```

In the other hand, when you add a property to an object using `this` keyword you're not adding it to the built-in `window` object. This is why the closure won't locate `this.a` as just `a`.

If you don't qualify a property name with `this` it's a variable that can be local or global - understanding *global* as a property of `window` object -.

JavaScript runtime looks for a variable in its current scope, otherwise in the parent scope, and so on, until it reaches global scope and, if `window` doesn't own a property - actually the variable identifier -, your browsers or any JavaScript runtime will determine that the variable is *undefined*.

Answer (score 0):

In your first example, `this.a` is scoped to the `this` context of `foo`. If you change your code to this:

```
function foo() {
   var a = 'a';
   this.bar = function() { console.log(a); }
}

new foo().bar();
```

It will work. Otherwise you have to do this:

```
function foo() {
   this.a = 'a';
   this.bar = function() { console.log(this.a); }
}

new foo().bar();
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason your first code example doesn't work is that:

```
console.log(a);
```

is looking for a variable named `a` in scope of the `bar()` method.  But you have never declared such a variable.  You've only declared a property on some other object with the name `a`.  If you want to refer to that property, you have to use the appropriate object reference like this:

```
console.log(this.a);
```

All properties in Javascript MUST include the object that the property is on in order to access them except for properties on the global object which are treated as global variables.  So, `a` is not the same thing as `this.a` in your context.

Variables are only global if they are declared in the global scope or explicitly attached to the global object (which is `window` in a browser) or if they are implicitly assigned to without declaration and you are not in strict mode (I call these accidental globals and consider them a horrible thing).

---

So, here are a couple things you could do.

Use a public instance variable:

```
function foo() {
   this.a = 'a';
   this.bar = function() { console.log(this.a); }
}

new foo().bar(); // outputs the member variable a
```

Or use a constructor local variable (essentially a private instance variable):

```
function foo() {
   var a = 'a';
   this.bar = function() { console.log(a); }
}

new foo().bar(); // outputs the member variable a
```

Or use an actual global (not recommended):

```
var a;
function foo() {
   a = 'a';
   this.bar = function() { console.log(a); }
}

new foo().bar();   // outputs the global a
```

Comment: I know, but the first example is an example of running a function (`bar`) in a context that contains a property with the name (`a`) of a variable referred to by a function within that context. The same can be said of the second example because of the peculiar way in which variables become properties on the global object.

Comment: @BenAston - and what is your question about that?  All property references in Javascript MUST include the object that the property is contained on except properties on the global object which are actually treated as global variables.  Also, note that I now have three code examples.

Comment: My question is: I established in my comment some equivalence between the two examples in my question. Yet the first fails, the second "works". Does the interpreter maintain metadata about the properties defined via variables on the global object, so that they can be referred to (per normal variables)? I am specifically interested in the behavior surrounding the "weird" behavior of variables on the global object becoming properties.

Comment: @BenAston - there is a search hierarchy when the interpeter tries to resolve a variable name that does not have an object reference.  It looks first in the current function for local variables.  It then looks in any parent function scopes.  It then looks on the global object.  It NEVER looks on the `this` object.  It will ONLY ever find a variable on the `this` context if you actually refer to it as `this.a`.  Javascript is NOT like some other languages that look on the current object context for named variables.  It does not do that.

Comment: @BenAston - and you didn't establish any equivalency between your two examples.  One doesn't work.  The other is written an entirely different way.  You might think they are equivalent in your thinking, but they are not.

Comment: OK, maybe equivalency is the wrong word. "Strong similarity" then. The first example is an example of running a function (`bar`) in a context that contains a property with the name (`a`) of a variable referred to by a function within that context (the context being `Foo`). The second example is an example of running a function (`bar`) in a context that contains a property with the name (`a`) of a variable referred to by a function within that context (the context being the global object).

Comment: @BenAston - I'm not sure you've quite understood yet that Javascript does NOT look on the current `this` context to resolve naked symbols.  It just doesn't do that.  That's why your first example can't and won't work.

Comment: "I'm not sure you've quite understood yet that Javascript does NOT look on the current this context to resolve naked symbols." I understood that from the outset. It turns out it **does** for the case of the global object - this latter observation was the crux of my question. My question might have been clearer, but I did say the first example wouldn't work "obviously". I knew when writing the question why the first example did not and will never work.

Comment: @BenAston - Javascript always looks at the global context (the last place it looks for a naked symbol) and that has nothing to do with any value of `this` or any context.  I described the exact sequence the interpreter uses to resolve symbols in an earlier comment.  If you understand now (I really can't quite tell), then I guess we're done.

Comment: My question has nothing to do with the `this` keyword. I mention the keyword `this` twice in my example merely to set properties on the `foo` instance.

Comment: @BenAston - Is there any part of this that you still don't understand?  I don't know what we're still discussing.  In Javascript, except for global variables, an object reference is ALWAYS required to access a property of an object and that includes all instance properties.  Your first code example assigns `this.a` which makes `a` a property of an object and not a global so thus an object reference will always be required to access that property as in `something.a`.  In your specific example, you can't access `this.a` without using `this.a` so it seems your question is entirely about `this`.